# Vista laptop newly added user cannot see existing folders

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have a Vista laptop and I have added a new user. My problem is the newly added user is not able to see existing folders in Windows Explorer.  How can I make these new folders visible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you means specific folders made on one account are not visible on other accounts? Because the specific folders for one account are not visible for another user if that is what the problem is..

Comment: Thank you Tjekkles: any folders which is not meant specific to any particular user which are not visible